# Selecting 18.04 toolchain on snapcraft.io for automatically updating qt5 snap on github commit

Tags: snapcraft

Is it possible to select newer (than 16.04) toolchain on snapcraft.io with [snapcraft.yaml](https://github.com/mispp/goat/blob/master/snapcraft.yaml) options? Based on irc suggestion i tried `base: core18`, but it didn't work.

Currently, I'm making this snap locally using ubuntu 18.04. What i want to do is to trigger automated build on github commit. QT5 application like it is now cannot be built using 16.04 toolchain.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Specified base: core18, but it's still installing on core16. Not sure if there's an obvious step I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that at the time of the question build service didnt have 18.04. Now the build works fine.